# What am I doing wrong? Traceback error for Python

Tags: python-3.x, debugging

I have this code that needs to print out Fred's grade with a midterm score of 87 and a final score of 92. What am I missing?

This is for a homework assignment and my teacher says it needs to be formatted this way and when she did this the code ran but it's not working for me.

```
print("Section 7.1 Practice Problem 1")
print("Answer to Problem 1 =")


def __init__(self):
    st = LGstudent
    name = input("Enter student's name: ")
    st.setName(name)
    midterm = float(input("Enter student's grade on midterm exam: "))
    st.setMidterm(midterm)
    final = float(input("Enter student's grade on final exam: "))
    st.setFinal(final)
    print("\nNAME\tGRADE")
    print(st)


class LGstudent:
    def __init__(self, name="", midterm=0, final=0):
        self._name = name
        self._midterm = midterm
        self._final = final

    def setName(self, name):
        self._name = name

    def setMidterm(self, midterm):
        self._midterm = midterm

    def setFinal(self, final):
        self._final = final

    def calcSemGrade(self):
        average = (self._midterm + self._final) / 2
        average = round(average)
        if average >= 90:
            return "A"
        elif average >= 80:
            return "B"
        elif average >=70:
            return "C"
        elif average >=60:
            return "D"
        else:
            return "F"

    def __str__(self):
        return self._name + "\t" + self.calcSemGrade()
```

Every time I print, I receive a traceback error saying that st.setName is unfilled.